# Java chat client&server not receiving

Tags: java

I'm working on a chat client for a class and running into some issues that I can't seem to find. in both *ChatWindow* and *EchoServer*, all of the system print lines are working properly except one, it never gets to "server responded". Every time it attempts to send to the server, it follows and properly prints out what it is supposed to be sending out, but the server never receives anything. Does anyone have any ideas of what I'm running into here? Note, I'm not getting any errors either from the compiler or at runtime.

Still new to stackoverflow, please let me know if there's anything I can add to help here.

**Edit 1**: Still having same issue, but added while loop in EchoServer to fix error where server was closing immediately after connecting to client.

**Edit 2**: I've discovered that the socket is closing on me, and that's why the server was disconnecting, I just can't figure out now why the socket might be closing. My break point where I find a closed socket in the *ChatWindow* constructor, immediately after entering the newly created thread.

**Edit 3**: made the necessary repairs and the code is now working properly.

```
// Simple server to receive communication from a client on the same computer and echo it back
public class EchoServer {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
       try (ServerSocket s = new ServerSocket(4688)) {
        // wait for client connection
          try (Socket incoming = s.accept()) {
             System.out.println("client connected");
             try (Scanner in = new Scanner(incoming.getInputStream())) {
                PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(incoming.getOutputStream());
                out.println("Hello! Enter BYE to exit.");
                out.flush();

                System.out.println("sent message to client");

                // echo client input
                boolean done = false;
                while (true) {
                    while (!done && in.hasNextLine()) {
                       String line = in.nextLine();
                       System.out.println(line);
                       out.println("Echo: " + line);
                       out.flush();
                       if (line.trim().equals("BYE")) done = true;
                    }
                    if(done) break;
                }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}

// Client main class. runs next class
public class ChatProgram {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    JFrame frame = new ChatWindow();
                    frame.setTitle("Chat Program");
                    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(ChatProgram.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}



// accepts user input from a textField when button is pressed.
// gives it to the server and prints it in it's own textArea
// 
public class ChatWindow extends JFrame {
    private String username = "";
    private Scanner in;
    private PrintWriter out;
    private Socket s;
    public ChatWindow() throws IOException {
        initComponents(); // this initializes the gui
            try {
            s = new Socket("localhost", 4688);
            System.out.println("Connected to server");
            in = new Scanner(s.getInputStream());
            out = new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream());
            class PollServer implements Runnable {
                @Override
                public void run(){
                    while(true){
                        if(in.hasNextLine()){
                            System.out.println("server responded");
                            String input = in.nextLine();
                            PrintToWindow(input);
                        } 
                    }
                }
            }
            catch(IOException io) {
            //I'll do something with this
            }
            Thread t1 = new Thread(new PollServer());
            t1.start();
        }
    }

    // Connect will be used later
    public void Connect() {
        SendToServer("connect " + username);
    }

    // Disconnect will be used later
    public void Disconnect() {
        SendToServer("Disconnect " + username);
    }

    // Handles all outbound messages to the server
    public void SendToServer(String clientOut) {
        out.println(clientOut);
        PrintToWindow(clientOut);
        System.out.println("sending to server: " + clientOut); // Program hits this and prints     correctly every time
        out.flush();
    }

    // Handles adding anything to the client's textArea. Will be implementing Synchronized later
    public void PrintToWindow(String clientIn) {
        textArea.append(clientIn + "\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not exactly sure of the negative effects (though it wouldn't surprise me if the JVM optimizes it out anyways), but you don't need to define the `PollServer` class in the constructor like that. It would make the code a bit cleaner if you extracted it out to a separate class.

Comment: That's unfortunately only there as a requirement for my project

Comment: Take a different class then. That's horrible.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the issue. Turns out what was going on was simply that I was only declaring my socket locally in the constructor. So once the constructor finished, despite my global "in" and "out" variables, the socket disappeared. I have fixed the code to include the changes, and it is now working properly

Answer (score 0):

**Good that you have solved your problem. Here I have developed a simple one for you that might help you a lot.**

**Client Class**

```
public class Client {

    Socket s;
    int port = 7777;
    DataOutputStream dos;
    DataInputStream dis;
    String IPAddress = "localhost";
    String title = "Client";

    public Client() {
        try {
            s = new Socket(IPAddress, port);
            dos = new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
            dis = new DataInputStream(s.getInputStream());
            new Window(title, dos, dis);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Client();
    }
}
```

**Server Class**

```
public class Server {

    ServerSocket ss;
    Socket s;
    int port = 7777;
    DataOutputStream dos;
    DataInputStream dis;
    String title = "Server";

    public Server() {
        try {
            ss = new ServerSocket(port);
            System.out.println("Server is listenning for incoming connection...");
            s = ss.accept();
            dos = new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
            dis = new DataInputStream(s.getInputStream());
            new Window(title, dos, dis);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Server();
    }
}
```

**Common Window Class**

```
public class Window extends JFrame {

    JTextArea display = new JTextArea();
    JScrollPane jsp = new JScrollPane(display);
    JTextField write = new JTextField();
    String msg;
    DataOutputStream dos;
    DataInputStream dis;

    public Window(String title, DataOutputStream dos, DataInputStream dis) {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.dos = dos;
        this.dis = dis;
        add(jsp, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(write, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        setTitle(title);
        setSize(300, 200);
        setVisible(true);
        write.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {

            @Override
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent ke) {
                if (ke.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER) {
                    msg = write.getText();
                    write.setText("");
                    appendToDisplay(title + " : " + msg);
                    try {
                        dos.writeUTF(title + " : "+  msg);
                    } catch (Exception ex) {
                        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
                        appendToDisplay("Cannot write to ...");
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        new Thread() {
            String msgRead;

            @Override
            public void run() {
                while (true) {
                    try {
                        msgRead = dis.readUTF();
                        appendToDisplay(msgRead);
                    } catch (Exception ex) {
                        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
                        appendToDisplay("Sorry...");
                    }
                }
            }
        }.start();
    }

    public void appendToDisplay(String msg) {
        display.append(msg + "\n");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    }
}
```